# Nbitcoin node c#

Tags: bitcoin, nbitcoin

Можете помочь разобраться в данном вопросе. Создаю транзакцию на отправку денег, далее ее нужно "зарегистрировать" в системе, раньше делал так :

```
using (var node = Node.Connect(Network.Main, node_address))//, node_address
  {
                try
                {
                    node.VersionHandshake();


                    node.SendMessage(new InvPayload(transaction));

                    node.SendMessage(new TxPayload(transaction));
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                catch { }
            }
```

Все бы было хорошо, да иногда стала выходить ошибка `"The node is not in a connected state"`, на строке `node.VersionHandshake();`, но при этом деньги отсылались, смена ноды не помогла.

Тогда изменил немного код :

```
using (var node = Node.Connect(Network.Main))//, node_address
{
    try
    {
        node.VersionHandshake();


        node.SendMessage(new InvPayload(transaction));

        node.SendMessage(new TxPayload(transaction));
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

т.е явно ноду я не прописываю, но транзакции регистрируются, но иногда ошибка `The node is not in a connected state` все же появляется, но т.к деньги успешно отправляются я просто ловлю исключения, все бы было хорошо, но вот сегодня, при очередном тесте, опять вышла эта ошибка, но деньги при этом не отправились. И тут возникает вопрос, что можно сделать? одно дело, если бы всегда деньги не отправлялись при такой ошибке, тогда можно было бы ловить исключение и менять ноду (где-то читал, что ошибка на стороне ноды), но деньги отправляются, хоть и не всегда.